# Should I ask my boss if I'm about to get fired?

Tags: manager

So a little background info on me and the company I work for. For the past 3 winters I've been working for a pretty company doing snow removal, but this year I decided work for them in the spring as well doing lawn care.

I had no idea when we were starting until I got a call at 9pm one night telling me to be at our shop at 7am. OK, fine no problem. I was asked to wear steel toed boots. The only boots I had were old steel toed boots with no sole in them and I didn't have time to go get a new pair. So for the better half of that day I was in immense pain from wearing terrible boots which my boss was very upset over and I get that.

The next day was raining so we didn't work, but I went out and got a new pair of boots. In the evening I started to get back spasms which are common in my family so I called my boss and told him I can't come in the next day and he said that's OK.

A few days go by and I haven't heard anything about when we will be working next so I texted a coworker and he told me I really need to speak to our boss. So the next day I show up at work and my boss comes over to me and tells me I won't be needed that day and to go home, and I haven't heard from him since even though I know for a fact that they are working.

Sorry for the long story I'm just a little concerned if I'm about to lose my job.

Comment: _Should I ask my boss if I'm about to get fired?_ who better to ask? Definitely worth clarifying with them your position.

Comment: I do think that you are on the last resort list when someone is absent at the last moment. Do not expect a lot of hour.

Comment: "Boss, am I about to get fired?" - "Oh, right, I was going to come to that some time soon, but now that you have brought up the topic, let's deal with it now. Yes, you *are* fired."

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely talk to the boss about your situation and see what he is thinking.  You may have given your boss the impression that you're not to be counted on to work, and they may have the wrong idea.

You should ask your boss for a closed door meeting, where you can discuss what happened to you on that first day, and explain why it happened.  Let him know that you are able to work, and are willing to do what you need to do to prove to him that you are to be counted on, and you will be at work when they call.

He may just have the wrong idea, so the worst thing you can do is just let this go and hope for a good outcome.  You need to address this, don't be confrontational, don't storm in and demand to know if you're being fired.  Just ask for a meeting, talk to him about your situation, and maybe you'll find out they just didn't need you for those few days.  It's always a good idea to just talk it out.

Also, as Vers said, you should probably consider also just starting to look for a new job as well, as if being gone a day or 2 gets your boss mad enough to fire you, after all you've done for them in winter times, then maybe it's not a company worth your time to stay with.

Answer (score 0):

At worst, if you know they're working and you're not getting called to work, you can use that time to look for potential new jobs.

Asking if you're going to get fired seems very confrontational to me, and may be a bad move.

Honestly I think it's a bit hard to judge the situation from outside, you need to consider the situation with regards to your own past in the company, and if your co-workers ever were in a similar situation.

A good choice may be to talk with your coworkers though, see how much work there is and if you trust anyone you can ask them if they mentioned you at work.

TL:DR; Probably not a good idea to confront this heads-on.

Comment: I agree that literally asking "am I going to get fired?" might not be the best idea, as it invites a positive response (ie: "yes, you're fired.")  However, I strongly disagree that he shouldn't confront the issue head-on.  Talking to co-workers is just generating more scuttlebutt and supposition.  To clear the air, the only way is to ask the boss directly - just phrase the question differently.  ie: "I notice I'm being excluded from work shifts, is there a particular issue with my performance that I could address?"